# Position of "like" and "reblog" buttons on tumblr

Tags: css

I tried to add some buttons under posts on my *tumblr page* but they are displaying **incorrectly**. *Like* button has **right** position but *reblog* appears at the **beginning** of the post (and on the next posts reblog appears even **outside post block**). Also after first post text in the other posts moves **to the left side**. I don't know how to solve this problem.

- **Blog with problem**: [http://rkhmlvch.tumblr.com](http://http:%20//rkhmlvch.tumblr.com)
- **Original code**:
  [https://github.com/xSOADx/The-Default-Network/blob/master/Theme%20code](https://%20github.com/xSOADx/The-Default-Network/blob/master/Theme%20code)
- **Fragment with needed code**:

```html
<div id="buttons">{likebutton}</div>
<div id="buttons">{reblogbutton}</div>
```

- **Images**

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, if you're planning to use styles in a specific element, use ID. If you're planning to use styles repeatedly in multiple elements use Class. I will recommend that you change the ID's to class instead.

Example: `<div id="post">...</div>` to `<div class="post">...</div>` same goes to `<div id="buttons">...</div>`.

Anyway, back to your question.
Your first `<div id="post">...</div>` is inside `<div id="wrapper">` then the rest are outside it. Put the rest of your post inside `<div id="wrapper">` and all of them will be the same.

Next, for your buttons. Change it to this `<div class="buttons">...</div>` instead of `<div id="buttons">...</div>` then add styles to your CSS:

`.buttons { display: inline-block; margin: 5px; }`

Comment: I don't understand the second part. Could you explain? I'm just a beginner ahaha

Comment: It's ok, everyone starts from that. First change the `id="buttons"` to `class="buttons"` after that, add a new styles on the header: `.buttons { display: inline-block; margin: 5px; }`

Comment: It worked but **meta** still moves to the left side :( 
 https://s27.postimg.org/c81xrup4z/image.png

Comment: Don't worry we'll fix it. Search for `.postmeta` on your styles, it has this value `max-width: 1024px;` all you need to do is add `margin:0 auto;` after that & viola!

Comment: You are awesome ^_~. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Welcome bro! ;)